# Body doesn't fill 100% height of browser

Tags: html, css

There is a small space at the end of the `footer` element. I tried to get rid of it using `html,body:min-height: 100%` , it's not working. I used **flex** in body element, is it because of that?

link: [picture of unused space at end of footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei5Uv.png)

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #4ac29a;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.form-step {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgb(202, 201, 201);
  background-color: beige;
  /* margin: auto; */
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="form-step active">

    <h1 class="head-info">Personal Info</h1>
    <p class="para-info">Please provide your name,email address and phone number</p>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="firstname" class="fname">Name</label>
      <div class="input-effect">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
        <span class="focus-border">
                        <i></i>
                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="emailaddr" class="mail">Email Address</label>
      <div class="input-effect">
        <input type="email" id="emailaddr" name="emailaddr">
        <span class="focus-border">
                        <i></i>
                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="phoneno" class="phone">Phone number</label>
      <div class="input-effect">
        <input type="number" id="phoneno" name="phoneno">
        <span class="focus-border">
                        <i></i>
                    </span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- form 1 end -->

  <div class="form-step">

    <h1 class="head-info">Select your plan</h1>
    <p class="para-info">You have the option of monthly or yearly billing.</p>

    <div class="plan-opts">
      <div class="plan-opt">
        <img src="./images/icon-arcade.svg" alt="arcade-icon" />
        <div class="opt-flex">
          <h1 class="opt-title">Arcade</h1>
          <p>$9/mo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- form 2 end -->

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="btn-section">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-next">Next</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In the running example it isn't....

Comment: yeah, but when i run through browser, there is a gap as shown in pic.

Comment: Have you checked if your footer element has a margin-bottom, bottom positioning or similar? You don't have to guess which elements cause what. Use the browser's developer tools, it can show which CSS rules cause the styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `min-height: 100dvh;` to the `body`:

```
body {
  min-height: 100dvh;
}
```

Comment: no bro, not working.

Comment: check this: https://codepen.io/redouane-bekkouche/pen/gOWEMjd

Comment: Now it worked, it was the **next** button animation problem. I didnt added button animation code here. Thank you red1dev.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in css file.

```
  body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, not working. maybe I need to check the next button animation. I didnt added button animation code here. Code snippet here is working fine.

Comment: it is working for me you can check here [link](https://rb.gy/56r3dz)

Comment: It worked, it was the next button animation problem. Thank you for the help amisha

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #4ac29a;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.form-step {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px rgb(202, 201, 201);
  background-color: beige;
  /* margin: auto; */
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="form-step active">

    <h1 class="head-info">Personal Info</h1>
    <p class="para-info">Please provide your name,email address and phone number</p>

    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="firstname" class="fname">Name</label>
      <div class="input-effect">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
        <span class="focus-border">
          <i></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="emailaddr" class="mail">Email Address</label>
      <div class="input-effect">
        <input type="email" id="emailaddr" name="emailaddr">
        <span class="focus-border">
          <i></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="phoneno" class="phone">Phone number</label>
      <div class="input-effect">
        <input type="number" id="phoneno" name="phoneno">
        <span class="focus-border">
          <i></i>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- form 1 end -->

  <div class="form-step">

    <h1 class="head-info">Select your plan</h1>
    <p class="para-info">You have the option of monthly or yearly billing.</p>

    <div class="plan-opts">
      <div class="plan-opt">
        <img src="./images/icon-arcade.svg" alt="arcade-icon" />
        <div class="opt-flex">
          <h1 class="opt-title">Arcade</h1>
          <p>$9/mo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- form 2 end -->

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="btn-section">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-next">Next</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```